# ListView cells grow bigger than the Node they contain

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx

again I'm working on the GUI for my university project,
I have to display a series of elements, defined by their color, in a row.
Since they can change at runtime i used a ListView.
There can't be more than four elements, and they're supposed to occupy a defined amount of space, but when I put the nodes inside the list's cells, the cell displays a border around the node (a rectangle in this case) which makes the ListView go out of his preferred sizes and display both the scrollbars, which i don't want to see since the List is not supposed to be scrollable plus it's really tiny so the bars cover almost all of it.

Here's the code I wrote for the cell factory:

```
private void initializeBalcony(SimpleListProperty<String> balconyProperty, ListView<String> balconyView) {
        balconyView.setBorder(null);
        balconyView.setItems(balconyProperty);
        balconyView.setCellFactory(row -> new ListCell<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty)
                    Platform.runLater(() -> this.setGraphic(null));
                else {
                    this.setMaxSize(27.5, 38);
                    Rectangle councillor = new Rectangle();
                    councillor.setWidth(20);
                    councillor.setHeight(35);
                    councillor.setFill(Paint.valueOf(item));
                    Platform.runLater(() -> this.setGraphic(councillor));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Plus the FXML definition of the ListView :

```
<ListView fx:id="coastBalcony" fixedCellSize="38.0" layoutX="80.0" orientation="HORIZONTAL" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="120.0" />
```

[Graphical display of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mq9H.png)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, maybe I should just use and HBox, but I used to have problems with ListChangeListeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `fixedCellSize="38.0"`, which in case of `HORIZONTAL` orientation is a width of the cell. So you should set it to desired value (from your example I guess it's 27.5). 
Also you might want to get rid of cell padding, either by setting it manually in your ListCell implementation using setPadding(new Insets(0)) or in css:

```
.list-cell {
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```